# In Ansible, how do I add a line without delete comment?

Tags: regex, ansible

I want to add the lines that don't exist, without deleting the comments of the lines that already exist.

my /tmp/file

```
line1
line2 #comment2
line3 #comment3
```

my playbook

```
---

- hosts: all
  vars:
    varlist:
      - line1
      - line2
      - line3
      - line4
      - line5

  tasks:
  - name: "Add line"
    lineinfile:
      dest: "/tmp/file"
      regexp: "^{{ item }}.*"
      line: "{{ item }}"
      state: present
      create: yes
    with_items:
     - "{{ varlist }}"
```

expectation of the result.

```
line1
line2 #comment2
line3 #comment3
line4
line5
```

real result.

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

I tried it that way, but it didn't work either.

```
  - name: "Add line"
    lineinfile:
      dest: "/tmp/file"
      backrefs: yes
      regexp: "^{{ item }}(.*)"
      line: '{{ item }}\1'
      state: present
      create: yes
    with_items:
     - "{{ varlist }}"
```

Comment: I'd suggest considering use of [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/template_module.html) module or other modules (`replace`, `blockinfile`) as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/lineinfile_module.html) for your use case.

Comment: I cannot use jinja2 or blockfile, the file is automatically generated by an application.
And sometimes comments are added at the end of the line.
Ansible would just have to ensure that some lines exist, without duplicating.

Answer (score 1):

I think you likely ran afoul of how `lineinfile:` thinks about the world, where your requirements fell into a "middle ground" that was triggered by the use of `backrefs: true`, which causes the behavior when `regexp:` failed to match (and its `insertafter:` friend) to be weird

I do appreciate this is a lot of jinja2, but it *does* do what you asked. If there are other more ansible-y ways, I'm sure others can chime in with their answers and you can pick the one you like the best

```yaml
  - name: read it in
    slurp:
      path: /tmp/file
    register: the_file
  - name: chop it up
    set_fact:
      # this creates a dict[str, str] consisting of any non-space terms
      # mapped to their "tail" on the line; it also tosses out blank lines,
      # if that matters in your case
      file_parts: >-
        {%- set results = {} -%}
        {%- for line in the_file.content | b64decode | split(cr) -%}
        {%-  set ma = line | regex_findall("^([^ ]+)(.*)") -%}
        {%-  for it in ma if it|length > 0 -%}
        {%-    set _ = results.update({it[0]: it[1]}) -%}
        {%-  endfor -%}
        {%- endfor -%}
        {{ results }}
    vars:
      cr: "\n"
  - name: write it back out
    copy:
      dest: /tmp/file
      content: |
        {% for v in varlist %}
        {{ v ~ file_parts.get(v, "") }}
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I cannot use jinja2 or blockfile, the file is automatically generated by an application.
And sometimes comments are added at the end of the line.
Ansible would just have to ensure that some lines exist, without duplicating.

Comment: Well, your question didn't include that requirement, so I solved what was written. FWIW the statement "I cannot use jinja2" is meaningless -- even your question contains multiple jinja2 expressions. But, as I said, if you don't like this approach, you can hold out for someone to give you a better one. Good luck